# Show that the heat kernel on $\mathbb{S}^1$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{-\frac{(x-y-2k\pi)^2}{4t}} $

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

The heat kernel on a smooth manifold $M$ is defined to be the solution of
$$(\Delta_x-\partial_t)H(x,y,t)=0,\qquad \text{in}~ M\times M\times (0,+\infty)$$
with initial data $\lim_{t\to 0}H(x,y,t)=\delta_x(y)$ in the sense of distribution, where $\delta_x(y)$ is the point mass at $x.$

I have already known that the heat kernel on $\mathbb{S}^1$ is
$$H(x,y,t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}+\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-k^2t}\cos k(x-y)\tag{1}$$
occasionally I find in [Heat kernels...](https://alexander-teplyaev.uconn.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/1703/2020/02/HK-circles-interval.pdf) that the heat kernel on $\mathbb{S}^1$ can also be written as
$$H(x,y,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{-\frac{(x-y-2k\pi)^2}{4t}}\tag{2}$$
so how can I show that they are in fact the same thing? I wonder this is related to the uniqueness of solution, but I am not good at PDEs, can someone help me?

Comment: I figure it out! It suffices to apply the Possion summation formula to the function $f(x)=e^{-\pi a x^2}$ with suitable constant $a$.

Comment: You should post your solution so that this question does not unnecessarily get bumped by Community in the future.